# How to use props inside map function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created small function can't get props value, I am using map function but I could not send props  used this props  **NewState={this.props.empname}** could not send props this component **ModalDelete**. How do I solve this.

ViewEmpList.js

```
      {this.props.filteredEmployee.map((emps, index) => {
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <th scope="row">{emps.empid}</th>
            <td>{emps.empname}</td>
            <td>{emps.empid}</td>
            <td>{emps.email}</td>
            <td>{emps.mobile}</td>
            <td style={{ color: "green" }}>
              <div className="divtext">Active</div>
              <div className="divshow"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <BiEditAlt
                className="fontcolor"
                style={{ fontSize: 35 }}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              {/* <RiDeleteBin2Fill
                className="fontcolor"
                style={{ fontSize: 35 }}
              /> */}
               {/* <ModalDelete onClick={()=>{this.takeValue(emps)}}/> */}
               <ModalDelete NewState={this.props.empname}/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
```

ModalDelete.js

```
<div className="modal fade col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="staticBackdrop" >
                        <div className="modal-dialog  modal-dialog-centered ">
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <h5 className="modal-title btn-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Are You sure want to delet it?</h5>
                                    <TiDeleteOutline Style="color:#fff;font-size:18px;" type="button" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body">
                                   {this.props.NewState} 
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button"  className="btn-delet" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What's happening? Is there an error? Is the prop defined in the parent? etc. Without a [mcve], it's hard to tell!

Comment: Did you meant to use `emps.empname` instead of `this.props.empname`?

Comment: What do you mean by "could not send props"? You are not receiving the **NewState** props inside the **ModalDelete** component?

Please do **console.log(this.props.empname)** inside your parent component and do **console.log(this.props.NewState)** inside your child component and see the result.